# The next Michael's neat primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Concatenate the first k prime numbers and then rearrange all the original digit's positions into successive digits from smallest to largest:

- k=1: 2 (prime)
- k=2: $23$ (prime)
- k=3: $235$ (composite)
- k=4: $2357$ (prime)
- k=5: $235711$ $=>$ $112357$ (composite)
- k=6: $23571113$ $=>$ $11123357$ (composite)
- k=7: $2357111317$ $=>$ $1111233577$ (composite)
- k=8 to k=21 are composites,
- k=22 (prime)
- k=$31$ (prime)
- k=$32$ to k=$300$ are composites

  (Leading zeros can be omitted, because for example $0123$ and $00123$ are equal $123$).I call such prime number as Michael's neat prime. Are there anymore Michael's neat primes after those five I found ?

Comment: No more up to $k=1000$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, that's very fast , how you do that ? : )

Comment: With a Maple program.

Comment: Heuristically, the number obtained for $k$ has on the order of $k \log k$ digits and thus probability on the order of $1/(k \log k)$ of being prime.  since $\sum_k 1/(k \log k)$ diverges, we might expect infinitely many primes to occur.  But since this series diverges extremely slowly, we might have to go to very large $k$ to find the next one.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, thanks for that amazing observations : )

Comment: I didn't find anything up to 10,000 other than the known 1,2,4,22,31.